# Why after append data in dropdownlist, form submit sends null value for dropdown in controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to send selected data from dropdownlist to Controller when form submit. Currently, When I check the `model` the dropdown `Category` shows `null`.

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult _pEdit(ViewModel model)
    {
   try{

     // does some functionality
       return Json(new { success = true});
      }
     catch
      {
       return Json(new { success = false });
       }

    }
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("_pEdit", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Editform", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="modal fade" id="EditModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">                                             
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category, Model.CategoryList, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>                  
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Script

```
//Dropdown
         $(document).on("click", '.LinkId', function () {
                var url = $(this).data("url");
                var Category = $("#Category");
                $.getJSON(url, { id: $(this).val() }, function (response) {
                    Category.empty().append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select'));
                    $.each(response, function (index, item) {
                        Category.append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
                    });
                    $('#EditModal').modal('show');
                });
            })

$('#Editform').submit(function () {          
        var formdata = new FormData($('#Editform').get(0));
        console.log(formdata);
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("_pEdit", "Home")',
      type: 'POST',
      data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                debugger;
                $('#Editform').get(0).reset();
                $('#EditModal').modal('hide');
            }
            else
            {
                var message = response.message;
                alert(message);
            }
        }
     });
    return false;
})
```

Comment: Since it looks like you're using Bootstrap's modal plugin, I would start by moving the form inside the modal-body div, as shown in the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content). Bootstrap's modal plugin manipulates the DOM, so you're probably not working with the correct "copy" of the form when submitting. What do you see in the console from `console.log(formdata);`?

Comment: @TiesonT., When I submit the form, I do not see value inside `console.log(formdata);`. What you suggest me to do.

Comment: What _do_ you see in the console? If nothing, that would seem to confirm that the way you're using the modal is incorrect.

Comment: @TiesonT., what should it show? Like selected value from dropdown or what

Comment: It will show the FormData object you just created. If it shows no field values, it's because the form doesn't currently contain any successful elements.

Comment: @TiesonT., Then how can I do that. If place `form` inside `panel-body` then how should I access submit form

Comment: I assume you mean `modal-body`?

Comment: @TiesonT., Sorry, Yes I mean `modal-body`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177237/discussion-between-mvc-and-tieson-t).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the way Bootstrap's modal works, you need to include the form tag itself inside the modal if you want to serialize the contents. So, your first step is something like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="EditModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("_pEdit", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Editform", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                {
                    <div class="form-group">                                             
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category, Model.CategoryList, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>   
                }               
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" id="submit-modal" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, you have a few options for "submitting" the form. I would trigger the form's submit event when the appropriate button is clicked:

```
// I added an ID to the markup above...
$(document).on('click', '#submit-modal', function(e){

    $('#Editform').trigger('submit');

});
```

Then your code should more or less work as-is.

If you're interested in a slightly easier option (IMO), you might find [bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html#prompt-with-select) useful. *Disclosure: I am currently a maintainer of bootbox*.

Comment: Can I place `<div class="modal-footer">` inside `}` bracket.

Comment: You can, but the modal may not render correctly. The Bootstrap styles expect it to be a sibling of the modal-body, not a child.

Comment: Ok. Should I write this code `$('#Editform').trigger('submit');` inside it

Comment: "inside it" - inside what?